# Move through list and keep state

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to transform this pseudocode into Haskell:

```
function whatever(list)
    int somestate
    foreach list as item
        if item === 1
              state++
        else 
              state--
    endforeach
    return state
```

Now something like this is obviously wrong (state is 3):

```
test :: [Int] -> Int
test item
       | head item > 1 = 1
       | otherwise = newItem
       where newItem = tail item
```

What is the best way to achieve something like this in Haskell?

Comment: it's a fold. what's the initial state?

Comment: Also read up on persistent data...

Comment: Usually using `head` and `tail` are *antipatterns*: one better uses pattern matching here, since it is more safe, and easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this simply by using another parameter to the function:

```
test [] counter = counter
test (x:xs) counter
    | x == 1 = test xs (counter + 1)
    | otherwise = test xs (counter - 1)
```

Here we use pattern matching `(x:xs)` to bind the head of the list to x, and the tail of the list to xs. Once we get to the empty list, we return the final counter.

We'd have to call this function with an initial counter, like so

`test [1..3] 0`

However, we can do this better by not having to pass in an initial counter, by accumulating the counter as we go, like so.

```
test [] = 0
test (x:xs)
    | x == 1 = test xs + 1
    | otherwise = test xs - 1
```

This time, each time the value is equal to one, we add one to the result of the function on the empty list. Eventually we will meet the base case, which is 0, and the rest of the values will be added up giving us the final value.

However, this pattern of recursing over a list and doing something which the value is very common. We can use a fold:

```
test = foldl' (\acc x -> if x == 1 then acc + 1 else acc - 1) 0
```

This is essentially our previous recursive function.

There are ways to store persistent state in Haskell, but generally we don't need them in simple cases like this.

Comment: In your recursive case, I think you can make this more efficient by doing `1 + test xs` and `(-1) + test xs` so it's tail recursive and can ditch the preceding reference frame.

Comment: You may want to use `foldl'` if you have a long list so that you don't build up a giant thunk that causes a stack overflow (bingo) when evaluated.

Comment: @AdamSmith `1 + test xs` is still `(+) 1 (test xs)`. The outmost call is still `(+)`, not `test`; it won't change anything about TCO.

Comment: @HTNW thanks for the correction! My CS is a little rusty, been in the weeds too long :)

Comment: This answer was the most readable for me as a haskell beginner. 
So foldl' would be the way to go in Haskell for these sort of problems?

Comment: @SparklingWater (if I may interject) yes. there's even a saying that `foldl'` should almost always be used in place of `foldl`.

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd probably do this:

```
whatever xs = length ones - length others where
    (ones, others) = partition (1==) xs
```

The only thing that would give me pause is some consideration for long lists; if it is important that the list not be all in memory at once, this wouldn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
> sum . map (bool (-1) 1 . (==1)) $ [1,2,2]
-1
> sum . map (bool (-1) 1 . (==1)) $ [1,2,2,1]
0
> sum . map (bool (-1) 1 . (==1)) $ [1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]
4
```

Note that `bool (-1) 1 . (==1)` can also be written using basic syntax as

```
(\x -> if x==1 then 1 else -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just tweak it and shuffle a few words around, like

```
foo (list) = 
    -- int somestate
    -- foreach list as item   
    -- foreach item in list
           do  item <- list
               if item == 1
                 then  return incr -- state
                 else  return decr -- state
    -- return state

incr state = state + 1
decr state = state - 1
```

and already get yourself a *thing*, with a *type* deduced for it! which is

```
foo :: (Num a, Num b, Monad m, Eq a) => m a -> m (b -> b)
```

We know `m ~ []` so it's actually

```
foo :: (Num a1, Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> [b -> b]
```

So, what can we do with the bunch of state-updating functions, like `incr`/`decr`, in a row? A couple of things:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable

sequence . foo    :: (Num a, Num b, Eq a) => [a] -> b -> [b]

foldr (.) id . foo :: (Num a, Num b, Eq a) => [a] -> b -> b

appEndo . foldMap Endo . foo 
                   :: (Num a, Num b, Eq a) => [a] -> b -> b

foldl (.) id . foo :: (Num a, Num b, Eq a) => [a] -> b -> b

appEndo . getDual . foldMap (Dual . Endo) . foo  
                   :: (Num a, Num b, Eq a) => [a] -> b -> b
```

Not the first one, certainly.

It would seem that the one with `foldl` is the ticket here. But then again, it goes against *non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem*. So really, it's

```
foo :: (Num t, Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> t -> t
foo = foldr g id 
    where
    g x r state | x==1 = r (incr state)     -- or even `r $! incr state`
             | otherwise = r (decr state)   --         `r $! decr state`
```

or simpler,

```
foo :: (Num t, Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> t -> t
foo = foldr g id 
    where
    g x r | x==1 = r . incr
       | otherwise = r . decr
```

or even just

```
foo :: (Num t, Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> t -> t
foo = foldr (\x -> if x==1 then (. incr) else (. decr)) id
```

which actually is the one with the `Dual` we had all along. I think. Have fun validating this (or otherwise). :)

---

*update:* Fusing `foldr (.) id . foo` into one function leads to an even nicer looking

```
foo :: (Num t, Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> t -> t
foo = flip $ foldr (\x -> if x==1 then incr else decr)
```

but it processes the state in the opposite order.

Comment: How does it compare to the foldl solution? And why would that not be the ideal way in Haskell?

Comment: there are two themes here. one thing is the direction of the state passing through the chain of state-updaters. with `incr` and `decr` specifically it doesn't matter of course, but in general it might. the other thing is to get it working right away, instead of waiting for the whole list to get waded through before the first state-updater starts working - which should be happening right away, ideally.